# Trying to enable certain input elements after the user enters the correct password is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Input elements from class "flex-container" and id "launch-button" are disabled in the HTML code. I would like to enable them after the user enters the correct password in the password input field and clicks on the "ok-button". Note: I also failed to disable the required input elements using Javascript and had to disable each one individually in the HTML page. Here is a Stack Snippet of the minimum necessary code to replicate the problem:

```js
const password = "TrustNo1";

document.getElementById("ok-button")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (document.getElementById("password").value == password) {
                document.querySelectorAll("input[disabled]")
                    .forEach(input => input.disabled = false);;
            }
        });
```

```html
<div class="space">
        <div class="control-panel">
            <div class="control-panel__inner">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                <input type="button" value="OK" id="ok-button">

                <div class="check-buttons flex-container">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="'flex-item" disabled>
                </div>

                <div class="levers flex-container">
                    <input type="range" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="range" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="range" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="range" class="flex-item" disabled>
                    <input type="range" class="flex-item" disabled>
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Launch" id="launch-button" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please reduce the code in the question to the minimum necessary to replicate the problem; see [mcve] for details. Ideally, make your MCVE **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: FWIW: `input.disabled = false` is just fine, so the problem isn't there.

Comment: @drip What browser did you use?

Comment: @lostperson Chrome, but I checked Edge right know and it also works on Edge.

Comment: @drip - FWIW, Chrome and Edge > v44 are effectively the same thing from JavaScript/DOM perspective (as they're both Chromium derivatives).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but I also know that some people don't know so I wrote it so people don't say: "but did you already try Edge?"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element (the original just had the code running before the elements were in the DOM).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input:disabled")
                        .forEach(input => input.disabled = false);
```

use the :disabled selector.

EDIT:

ok, you're code should work, however, I noticed that your script tag is at the top of the page. This means the JS will run before the page is done loading.

try putting the script tag at the bottom of the body. This will make it so that all the markup is rendered before the script runs.

Comment: I also had my doubts about `input[disabled]`. It works on Chrome, and *should* work reliably cross-browser, but `:disabled` would definitely be the better choice. No idea whether this is what's wrong with the OP's code, though.

Comment: I think this is what is wrong with the code. However, I tried a fiddle, and what he did should also work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked right after I put the script before the </body> tag.

Comment: Interestingly, it works in stack snippet without changing anything.

Comment: @lostperson - That's because Stack Snippets put the code you put in the JavaScript pane at the end of the HTML.